# Searching Java Collection Against A String

Tags: java, regex, search, collections

I have a collection which has following structure...

```
ArrayList<String[]> schools = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I also have a string say **"United Berkley"**

Now I want to search **"schools"** for the above mentioned string and return **String[]** if there is any match in any the **String[]** array.

I have that basic code but lost to find desired **regex** for it.

```
String target = this.Schools.get(s)[a];
if (target.matches("*")) {
   schools.add(this.Schools.get(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `schools` data structure looks a bit... weird.

Are you sure what you wanted is not `ArrayList<String>` ?

If that's the case, then you can just use:

```
if (schools.contains("United Berkley"))
```

Comment: No, it's just ArrayList<String[]> and it has to match everything inside String[0...6]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
        List<String[]> schoolsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String [] schools = {"United Berkley","Super Standford"};
        schoolsList.add(schools);
        String target = "United Berkley";
        for(String [] school:schoolsList){
            Arrays.sort(school);
            int position = Arrays.binarySearch(school,target);
            if(position>=0){
                System.out.println("Found target");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Target is not in the list");
            }
        }
```

prints "Found target".

Comment: Though it probably doesn't matter here, you should warn that `Arrays.sort` is going to modify `school` (maybe that order matters for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Just use String.equals(your-String) and loop through the array to match the schools. Or use list.contains(your-String)
 But I guess using a HashMap will provice better access times for that kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression to search for a known string - just use `target.equals ("United Berkley")`.  You can make it easier on yourself by making sure that your String[] arrays are sorted - use [Arrays.sort (...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to keep them in order and the use Arrays.binarySearch (...) to search them quickly.

I do question the layout of your data structures though - it doesn't seem like the most natural way to do what you want.  A `HashMap` or even a simple sorted `List` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression to search for a known string - just use `target.equals ("United Berkley")`.  You can make it easier on yourself by making sure that your String[] arrays are sorted - use [Arrays.sort (...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to keep them in order and the use Arrays.binarySearch (...) to search them quickly.

I do question the layout of your data structures though - it doesn't seem like the most natural way to do what you want.  A `HashMap` or even a simple sorted `List` seem more appropriate.